# Why are so many terminal codes not recognized by Python?

Tags: python, terminal

So many of the python terminal codes I have tried have been unrecognized and outputs the following warning message:  'X' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Is this due to some sort of administration privileges? Am I perhaps misunderstanding what is and is not terminal code? Baffling.

Some of the terminal codes I have tried:

```
env HDF5_DIR=$PWD pip install tables

sudo python setup.py build_ext --inplace --hdf5=/opt/local --lzo=/opt/local --bzip2==opt/local

python -c "from pip import pep425tags;print(pep425tags.supported_tags)"
```

Comment: Is the Python executable in your PATH variable?

Comment: maybe there are some problems with the way it handles some chars like '$' within the first phrase, '/' at the second and ' " ' at the third?

Comment: @Tomothy32 I am not entirely sure what that means but I will try googling around about PATH variables. beteraba: it certainly could be part of the issue. How can I make sure that it handles those characters correctly?

Answer (score 3):

The following message is produced by the Windows shell:

> 'X' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

It has nothing to do with Python. It means that the command `X` is not installed on your Windows. For example, `env` and `sudo` are Linux commands, not Windows commands.

You must have not installed Python as well, or it has been installed somewhere where the Windows shell cannot find it.

Comment: Oh wow. I had no idea env and sudo were OS specific code. Thank you for letting me know. Not sure why the windows shell is not recognizing python-- its installed in C:\Users\account1\PycharmProjects\Attempt1\venv\Scripts which i dont think is anywhere prohibited but I will try installing under program files